# Ставится ли тире: "Остудил воду (?) называется..."

Tags: пунктуация

Остудил воду (?) называется...
Пошел купаться (?) называется...

Нужно ли здесь тире или, возможно, другой знак?

Answer (score 3):

You need a comma here.

Rosenthal, 99:

> Запятыми выделяются вводные слова и словосочетания. Различается несколько основных групп вводных слов по их значению:
>
> …
>
> 5) вводные слова, выражающие отношение к стилю речи, к характеру и способу изложения: *словом, одним словом, иными словами, другими словами, иначе говоря, коротко говоря, попросту сказать, мягко выражаясь, если можно так сказать, если можно так выразиться, с позволения сказать, лучше сказать, так сказать, что называется* и др.: слова *собственно, вообще, вернее, точнее, скорее* и т.п. являются вводными, если после них можно добавить слово *говоря*. Например: *...Правление уполномочило его ускорить работы, то есть, иными словами, он сам себя уполномочил к этому (Куприн); А Клавдия ушла, вернее, убежала, смущенно укрыв шалью лицо (Ю. Лаптев)*

Comment: "Rosenthal, 99"
Skip that comma and it will sound straight from the Bible.

Comment: @alamar: With comma shalt thou isolate the parentheses, em dash thou shalt not isolate with, but the comma.

Answer (score 0):

В приведённых примерах, `называется` является междометием, поэтому его нужно отделить запятой.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sarcasm. One wanted to have a bath, but he had only hot water in the pipes, so he decided to cool, and put a bucket of water to fridge,

1. but electricity was turned off, because of line disconnect. So one didn't has a bath.

or

2. but fridge was very powerful, or one forgot to remove the bucket from the fridge and got the ice.

And he says:

— Остудил воду, называется... Пошел купаться, называется...